# function foo that has the type ’a * ’a -> int

Tags: sml, smlnj

function foo that has the type `’a * ’a -> int`
So I tried writing some prog:

```
fun foo(x,y)=6;(*here the type is ’a * ’b -> int*)
fun foo(x,x) =5; (*gives error cause of two x*)
fun foo(x,y) = if true then x else y; (give 'a * 'a -> 'a)
```

What should I do to get `’a * ’a -> int`?

thanks

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19484929/ml-syntax-function-program

Comment: @Andreas Rossberg if I write something like : fun f(x,y)= if x=y then 0 else 1;  I get val f = fn : ''a * ''a -> int. What is the difference between 'a and ''a?

Comment: @Andreas Hah, I practically copy-pasted your answer without even reading it :)

Comment: @user987339 See my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track. It looks like you've understood that there are two parts to this problem: forcing `x` and `y` to have the same type, and forcing `foo` to return an integer.

You were close with `fun foo (x,x) = 5;`. I think you probably meant something like this:

```
fun foo (x,y) = if x=y then 1 else 0;
```

This gives `''a * ''a -> int`, which is very close, but not quite what you need. `''a` is not the same as `'a` - while one dash means "any type", two dashes mean "any type which can be compared for equality". In other words, we've restricted the types just by saying `x=y`.

You've identified one way of forcing the types to be the same: putting them in the result of an `if` expression. Now all that's left is to turn the result of the `if` (which has type `'a`) into an `int`. You could do that by putting it in a `case` expression, or passing it to another function with type `'a -> int`.

Or you could try something else. Every element in a list has to have the same type. So there's another way to restrict the types of `x` and `y`: put them in the same list. Then you've just got to figure out how to turn that list into an `int`.

Comment: Thank you so much Nick 
you cleared lots of my fundamental doubts. 

"(''a is not the same as 'a - while one dash means "any type", two dashes mean "any type which can be compared for equality".)"

Answer (score 1):

I guess the trick is to use `x` and `y` in a such way that SML can infer they are of the same type. So, I thought that since lists only contain elements of the same type, we could put `x` and `y` in to a list and that will tell SML that they are of the same type. Then we can calculate the size of the list to return an int, and voila!

```
fun foo(x,y) = 
    let
       val items = x::y::[]
    in
       List.length items
    end
```

The gives type: `'a * 'a -> int`

Comment: No need for the `items`, just `fun foo (x,y) = length [x,y]`

Answer (score 0):

You had a good start with:

`fun foo(x,y) = if true then x else y;`

So, you should change only return type of function. You should return some Int. And go with an explicit type.

In your case example could be:

```
fun  foo(x :'a, y : 'a) = 1;
```

But this is explicit definition. As stated below by [Nick Barnes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1104979/), solution should involve adding variables to a list:

```
 fun f(x,y) = let val z = [x,y] in 0 end;
```

Comment: fun  foo(x,y) = if true then 1 else 2; 
in this i am getting type
a' * b' -> int

I want a' * a' -> int

Comment: I tried your approach of
fun  foo(x,y) = if true then 1 else 2; 
in this i am getting type
a' * b' -> int

I want a' * a' -> int

Comment: Go with explicit type : fun  foo(x :'a, y:'a) = 1;

Comment: @user987339, I suppose this is a homework problem, and I also assume that explicit type annotations are not the point of the exercise.

Comment: Yes, it is actually a part of homework but it wasn't the question. I  was just curious to know how can a function has same type alpha and return any beta value.

BTW
Thank you so much for your time and patience.

Comment: `fun exactnum_helper(ls, k, count) = 
    if (ls = [] orelse count > 1) then (count > 1)
    else if ((hd ls) = k) then exactnum_helper(tl(ls), k, count+1)
    else exactnum_helper(tl(ls), k, count)
if count = k then true
else false

fun exactnum(ls, k) = 
    exactnum_helper(ls, k, 0);`

I am getting a syntax error now

Answer (score 0):

This one is short, and doesn't require any additional modules:

```
fun f (x, y) = 
  let val y = f (y, x) 
  in 5 end;
```

Though it doesn't terminate of course.

Comment: A nice short way to fix the return type to `int`: `fun f (x,y) = 1 + f (y,x)`. If you want something that will terminate, you could take advantage of the lazy if-else evaluation: `fun f (x,y) = if true then 1 else f (y,x)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here are three more ways to do it for your collection:

```
fun f1(x, y) = if false then f1(y,x) else 1

fun f2(x, y) = let val r = ref x
               in  r := y
                 ; 0
               end

fun f3(x, y) = let exception E of 'a
               in  (raise E x)
                   handle (E _) => (raise E y)
                                   handle E _ => 0
                end
```